# Duplicate identifier 'File'

Tags: typescript

I have checked every previous answer and I was not able to find a solution.

I have a monorepo using Lerna. I one of the projects I created a class named `File`. The following error is being thrown:

```
 error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'File'.

1 abstract class File {
                 ~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:5263:11
    5263 interface File extends Blob {
                   ~~~~
    'File' was also declared here.
  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:5268:13
    5268 declare var File: {
                     ~~~~
    and here.
```

root tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noLib": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules/**"]
}
```

project tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noLib": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": ["./src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules/**", "**/*.spec.ts", "**/*.test.ts"]
}
```

I have already tried:

- Adding the `skipLibCheck` setting set to true.
- Removing `typescript` from my dependencies and using the global 
  dependency.
- Using the flags `--skipLibCheck` and `--skipDefaultLibCheck` which of course where redundant.